# Dielectric with polar molecules

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity, electrostatics, dielectric

Suppose a dielectric slab contains polar molecules (which are not further polarisable). When placed in an electric field, (for simplicity, an uniform field), align themselves according to the field.

- Do they perfectly align so that all molecules have no net torque on them, or it is only a general arrangement which is less randomized and slightly prefers to have a net dipole moment according to the field?
- What effects in a dielectric will determine the extent of alignment?

There was a very poorly executed attempt to explain this with the thermal energy of the molecules i.e. $1/2k_b T$ at a temperature $T$. Can someone explain how the strength of the field and the thermal energy interact to determine the extent of alignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The electric field means that the potential energy of the polar molecule depends on it's angle relative to the field and [is given by](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53163/minimizing-potential-energy-of-a-dipole-in-an-electric-field):

$$ V(\theta) = -p E \cos\theta $$

where $p$ is the dipole, $E$ is the field strength and $\theta$ is the angle the dipole makes to the field lines. Obviously this has a minimum when the dipole is aligned with the field, so all else being equal the molecules will line up with the field.

However at any temperature greater than absolute zero there will be some thermal motion of the molecules, and interactions between molecules will randomly perturb the molecules away from their minimum energy conformation. The size of these perturbations is around $kT$ (per molecule), so if $kT$ is comparable with $2pE$ it will disrupt the alignment of the polar molecules and at temperatures significantly above $2pE/k$ the alignment will be lost completely. This means that generally speaking the dielectric constant will fall with increasing temperature.